# Imagen que se visualice en un JPanel y se visualice atraves de un proyector?

Tags: java

Hola gente buenas noches, les escribó para solicitar ayuda e información, he estado buscando por la internet y no encontré nada acerca del tema, sobre cómo podría hacer un programa en java, que cumpla con ciertos requisitos:

Que pueda seleccionar una imagen a través de un JFileChooser y mostrarla en un contenedor ya sea un Jpanel.

1.-Que esa imagen que se visualiza en el JPanel, pueda proyectarla utilizando un proyector , pero que solo se pueda visualizar la imagen que está cargada en el jPanel , mas no el programa ni el escritorio de mi pc.

2.-Quiero hacer algo parecido a lo que realiza el programa vMix. les agradeceria mucho su ayuda.

posdata: el requisito numero 1 ya lo he hecho , solo me falta hacer el numero 2, eso me tiene muy intrigado .

Answer (score 0):

Puedes mirar está clase para poder realizar lo segundo.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html

con el método getLocalGraphicsEnvironment podrás obtener todo lo que esté conectado y con getScreenDevices obtienes un arreglo de todos los dispositivos.

Al igual puedes encontrar más información en la siguiente liga

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627553/show-jframe-in-a-specific-screen-in-dual-monitor-configuration